# Where is the allocated space for flexible length array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Assume that I have a structure as below:

```
struct line {
       int length;
       char contents[];
};

struct line *thisline = (struct line *) malloc (sizeof (struct line) + this_length);
thisline->length = this_length;
```

Where is the allocated space for `contents`? In heap or in the coming address after `length`?

Comment: The array length is missing; it has to be `1`.

Comment: It is not missing, it is a flexible array member.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Not in C99 or later.

Comment: This is called a *flexible array member*, not a *variable length array*.  The two are different concepts in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both. It's in the heap, since `thisline` points to an allocated buffer in the heap. The extra size you've requested in the `malloc()` call serves as the allocated area for `thisline->contents`. Thus, `thisline->contents` begins right after `thisline->length`.

Answer (score 6):

The flexible array `contents[]` is by definition located inside the variable sized structure, after the `length` field, so you are right in `malloc` -ing space for it, so of course `p->contents` is sitting inside a zone that you `malloc`-ed (so inside the heap).

Answer (score 0):

There is **NO** implicitly allocated space for contents.

```
struct line foo;
// the size of foo.contents in this case is zero.
```

Always refer to it by means of using a pointer.
For example,

```
struct line * foo = malloc( sizeof(foo) + 100 * sizeof(char) );
// now foo.contents has space for 100 char's.
```

Comment: There is no *implicitly* allocated space.

Comment: Flexible or not, you cannot assign to an array.

Comment: @Jens, thanks for your help but I did mean `sizeof(foo)`, as I wanted to allocate enough space for a foo structure (which only has space for length but not contents) and the additional 100 char's for contents.